# Can't find whats wrong in the syntax to delete a row in sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Im trying to delete a row from the table given the name value in the row using the following line of code:

```
db.delete(Table, Column_Name+"="+ col_value, null);
```

Created table using:

```
db.execSQL("create table"+ Table+"("+Column_Name+" text," +Id+" integer primary key)");
```

Logcat shows NPE at the line of deleting the row. Whats wrong there in it?

Logcat:

```
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.example.databaseaccess.MainActivity.deleteone(MainActivity.java:70)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     ... 11 more
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.example.databaseaccess.DbHelper.fdelete(DbHelper.java:145)
07-31 18:00:13.267: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     ... 15 more
```

Line 144:  String s = Name+"="+"?";

Line 145:  db.delete(Table,s,new String[]{i});

Comment: npe probably means that your db is null

Comment: Give Spaces between Every words in bracks.

Comment: it has records pal. only problem is that the delete row syntax is missing something.

Comment: @njzk: You were right. I noticed later that i misspelt getWritableDatabase to getReadableDatabase. Now its allright. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The table was probably not created properly in the first place:

```
"create table"+ Table+"("
```

Make sure there is a space between "create table" and the name. So it should be

```
"create table "+ Table+"("
```

Comment: nice catch. A good advice is to ALWAYS Log.d() or something your String query when SQL access goes wrong ;)

Comment: Please post the full logcat error buddy, and line of code which it refers to

Answer (score 0):

```
db.delete(Table, String.format("%s = ?", Column_Name), new String[] {col_value});
```

Comment: This should be `db.delete(Table, Column_Name + "= ?", new String[] {col_value});`

Comment: yet the same result pals.